# Does microcontroller(esp32) uses x86 or arm, can I install Linux in these MCUs

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266, esp32

I was getting into microcontrollers so i was wondering either microcontrollers like esp32 and esp8266 and other similars are built on x86 or arm architecture?
I tried searching on the internet but didn't get enough clue

And if it is using any of these two architecture, is there any chance to install Linux in these controllers, i got this in my mind because freeRTOS are saying it is operating system for microcontrollers, and i think it is not

But somehow if it is an operating system so what about the other operating systems like Linux, do they have any chance to get installed in MCUs today? Or even do they have any chance in next five years?

Comment: esp32 is based on  a Tensilica Xtensa LX6, which is neither an ARM or x86 cpu.

Comment: Why do you think FreeRTOS is not an operating system for microcontrollers?  It most certainly is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From ESP8266EX datasheet :

> The ESP8266EX integrates a Tensilica L106 32-bit RISC processor, which
>   achieves extra- low power consumption and reaches a maximum clock
>   speed of 160 MHz. The Real-Time  Operating System (RTOS) and Wi-Fi
>   stack allow 80% of the processing power to be  available for user
>   application programming and development. The CPU includes the 
>   interfaces as below.

No ARM neither x86. It's Tensilica processor with own architecture.

At work I use STM32(ARM coretex-M) processors. It's technically possible to install linux on smaller MCU's like ARM cortex-M(https://elinux.org/STM32) and you have some linux distributions targeted to smaller chips(http://www.uclinux.org/) but usually linux is used on bigger chips(coretex-A)  A7, A8, A53(https://www.arm.com/products/silicon-ip-cpu).